# Refresh PHP sql query without refreshing page

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a question, and I'm hoping one of you will know the answer.

I am running a sql query from php fro a certain bit of information. I am then pulling that info into script and plugging it into an api. I want the api to have access to up to date info  every 30 seconds. However, obviously, although the script can run again every 30 seconds ... the php cannot, thus the info is the same.

Is it possible therefore to have the php that runs the sql query refresh once every 30 seconds without refreshing the entire page?

Or ... is there a better way to be doing this. I believe it is no a good idea to be accessing the database from javascript?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered just using a cron job?

Comment: The page can send ajax request for updated info, and then put the new data where you want to see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). There are plenty of tutorials on the net explaining how to create simple pages powered by AJAX.

A quick example can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PR9mW/1/).

```
(function() {
 setInterval(function() {
     $.ajax({
        async: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/echo/json',
        success: function(data) {
            // You'd use data variable here, but JSFiddle doesn't return anything
            $('#test').html(Math.floor(Math.random()*100)-1); // Changes randomly after every fetch
        }
     });
 }, 200); 
}());
```

Answer (score 1):

ajax is wath you are looking for,

ajax allows u to make a call to ur server whitout reloading your page.

i will recomend creating a page that only contains your data, then, on your aplication page load it into a div like

```
<div id="yourData"></div>
```

u can use James answer to load it, change '#test' for '#yourData' on any id u have on the div.

if u are using jquery u can use .load() also, for me is more clear, http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$('#yourData').load('YourAplication/YourDataGeneratorPage.html');
```